# Naming convention for Objective C initializers?

Tags: objective-c, naming-conventions

For Objective C clases like `NSString` with multiple initializers the convention seems to be to provide a default initializer `init` and then multiple `initWith...` initializers:

```
– init
– initWithBytes:length:encoding:
– initWithBytesNoCopy:length:encoding:freeWhenDone:
– initWithCharacters:length:
...
```

However, suppose I have an Objective C class that has *only one* initializer and that initializer takes multiple arguments. Does convention dictate that I still call it:

```
- initWithSomeStuff:thing1:thing2:thing3:
```

Or can it simply be called:

```
- init:thing1:thing2:thing3:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Avizzv92 wrote, every subclass of `NSObject` has the `-init` initialiser inherited from `NSObject`, so technically your subclass of `NSObject` would have two initialisers. A common practice is to have one *designated* initialiser and have other initialisers call it with default arguments.

As for your `-init:thing1:thing2:thing3:` idea, it is certainly possible. However, consider the following method definition:

```
- (id)init:(id)param0 thing1:(id)param1 thing2:(id)param2 thing3:(id)param3 {
    // …
}
```

It is easy to understand that `param1` refers to `thing1`, `param2` refers to `thing2`, and `param3` refers to `thing3`. But what is `param0`? That’s the reason why initialisers with parameters have names that start with `initWithSomething`: to make it clear what the first parameter is.

Answer (score 4):

All objects respond to the init method, even if it is not over-ridden by a subclass. As for your example I would still include "with" for sake of readability. Read out loud what the method is doing and you'll notice including "with" makes what your doing more poignent.

Comment: Love the concept of poignant method names